# How to get new value from textarea after firing "Change" event?

Tags: jquery, html, events

I'm trying to get the new value of textarea by using jQuery event "change" :

```
jQuery('#content').change(function(){

    alert(jQuery(this).html());

});
```

But whenever I change the content of the textarea, I always get the old value as a result.

Here is the example on JSFiddle : `http://jsfiddle.net/k4zKp/`

Comment: Change `.html()` to `.val()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
jQuery('#content').change(function(){

    alert(jQuery(this).val());

});
```